# Trigger Jenkins tests after commits in git submodules

Tags: git, jenkins, git-submodules, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a **super project** that only aggregates multiple git sumodules. I would like to trigger Jenkins for each change in submodules as well as when super project is updated.

```
/superproject
    /submodule-a
    /submodule-b
    /submodule-c
```

For each submodule I am using [Job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) and works fine except when some modules require others to compile or run tests -- that is one reason to aggregate all other repos in one *super project*.

**What should I do for testing individual submodules as well as integration as part of a super project?**

Comment: More context: [Best practice for multiple git repositories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211870/best-practice-for-multiple-git-repositories)

Answer (score 2):

I think this does not make sense. If [git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) is configured to trigger a job after `post-receive` hook in `remote` repository then it should work.

If a new commit is pushed to a submodule the parent project does not noticies. You must have to do:

```
git submodule update --remote --recursive
git commit
git push
```

Then, and only then, the job should receive the notification. For more information you could read:

- [Polling must die: triggering Jenkins builds from a git hook](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/)
- [How can I make Jenkins CI with git trigger on pushes to master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784329/how-can-i-make-jenkins-ci-with-git-trigger-on-pushes-to-master)